# How do i find all drop down lists in a page using Jquery

Tags: jquery

How do i loop thru all dropdown boxes in JQuery?

Comment: Perhaps you should add some information regarding what you're trying to do because $("select") gets a list of all dropdowns so is there some other issue?

Comment: This is too trivial that I would recommend to get yourself through the jQuery documentation and tutorials over there at jquery.com. If you prefer books, I can recommend the 'jQuery in Action'. Good luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

something like this should do the trick

```
$("select").each(function() {
    //do something with the select $(this) will give you the select element
});
```

Comment: or just, y'know, `$('select')`

Comment: I realized my mistake, input didn't even work

Comment: Hos do I loop thru in multiple divs?

Can I do $('#mydivname').find('select').each(function(){

});

??

Comment: are you looking for something like this $("#mydiv select").each(...) ?

Answer (score 9):

`$("select")` will include all the combo boxes too. To just get the drop down menus, use this:

```
$("select:not([size])")
```

To answer your other question:

> How do I loop thru in multiple divs? Can I do `$('#mydivname').find('select').each(function(){ });` ??

```
$('#mydivname select:not[size]').each(...)
```

Comment: Excellent use of attributes to narrow down to ONLY dropdowns